# How to timer-triggered multi-channel ADC conversion run in STMH7

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, adc, timer, dma

I've managed to get the timer-triggered ADC to run for single-channel conversions where an interrupt routine is called upon completion of the conversion. However, I need three channels to be converted and that is only possible via DMA according to ST's reference manual RM0399. I have very little experience with DMA with an STM32H745.

So far I have not been able to accomplish this using CubeIDE version 1.8.0. Here's what I believe to be the correct order of things:

[image]

Simply put:

1. Initialize the DMA, the timer and the ADC via the CubeMX generated routines `MX_DMA_Init()`, `MX_TIM6_Init()` and `MX_ADC3_Init()`.
2. Kick off the timer and start the ADC routine prepared specifically for DMA transfers.
3. Handle my results in my own routine `HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback()`.

I am sort of clueless where to look for where the chain of events is broken. I've set a breakpoint in `HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback()`, but it is never hit. Has anyone managed to get this to run and would care to share the recipe? What's missing in the code below?

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
uint16_t ADCValues[3];

int main(void) {
.
.
.
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_TIM6_Init();
  MX_ADC3_Init();

  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim6);
  HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc3, ADC_CALIB_OFFSET, ADC_SINGLE_ENDED);
  HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hdma_adc3, ADCValues, 3);

  while(1);
}
    
    
static void MX_TIM6_Init(void) {

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  htim6.Instance = TIM6;
  htim6.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim6.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim6.Init.Period = 47999;
  htim6.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim6);

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim6, &sMasterConfig);
}


static void MX_DMA_Init(void) {
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream1_IRQn);
}


static void MX_ADC3_Init(void) {
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  // Common configuration
  hadc3.Instance = ADC3;
  hadc3.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV4;
  hadc3.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_16B;
  hadc3.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_ENABLE;
  hadc3.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
  hadc3.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc3.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc3.Init.NbrOfConversion = 3;
  hadc3.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc3.Init.NbrOfDiscConversion = 1;
  hadc3.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIG_T6_TRGO;
  hadc3.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
  hadc3.Init.ConversionDataManagement = ADC_CONVERSIONDATA_DMA_ONESHOT;
  hadc3.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;
  hadc3.Init.LeftBitShift = ADC_LEFTBITSHIFT_NONE;
  hadc3.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
  HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc3);

  // Configuration of the three channels
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_13;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
  sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
  sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  sConfig.OffsetSignedSaturation = DISABLE;
  HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc3, &sConfig);

  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_14;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_2;
  HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc3, &sConfig);

  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_15;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_3;
  HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc3, &sConfig);
}

// Sharing the ADC results with the other core via the integrated SRAM4
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef *hadc) {

  // Here's where the breakpoint is set, but it is never reached
  int16_t  *tempPtr = (int16_t*) 0x38000000UL;
  *tempPtr       = ADCValues[0];
  *(tempPtr + 1) = ADCValues[1];
  *(tempPtr + 2) = ADCValues[2];
}
```

Comment: What ADC? What do the signals look like?

Comment: I am not sure how this is relevant as this is is a matter of getting some code running. In any case, if you look carefully at the code, you'll see it's ADC3, input channels INP13, INP14, and INP15. And I've also been able read to successfully get my analog signals converted via this inputs.